# Единственное число от слова "качели"

Tags: орфография, морфология, единственное-множественное-число

Интересно, а у слова **качели** есть единственное число?
В просторечии можно нередко услышать слово **качель** (даже ругательство есть — *тудыть его в качель*). Но как все-таки правильно?
И если единственного нет, то возникает другой вопрос: а почему число только множественное? Обычно такое происходит с вещами, имеющими что-то парное в своем составе: ножницы, колготки и т. д.

Answer (score 4):

Сразу скажу, что у Ильфа и Петрова "качель" явно заменяет площадную брань.

Теперь по сути.
Нормативной формы для единственного числа к "качели" нет. Её и не может быть потому, что нет объекта, который бы этим термином обозначался. 
Что касается просторечно-эвфемистической формы "качель", то она, видимо, соответствует не единственному числу качелей, а областному названию люльки, детского "спального места" (не хочу даже слово "кроватка" употреблять). Впрочем, последнее - весьма предположительно, возможно тут и еще что-то. Но на устройство популярного аттракциона перенесено явно искусственно.

Насчет парности - наблюдение интерсное, но не абсолютное. "Часы" например. 
Впрочем, для "качелей" можно вспомнить простейшую их конструкцию - доска, подпертая посередине, качаются на ней парами, с двух сторон. Надеюсь, понятно, о чем речь.

Кстати, у "качель" есть ещё одно, устаревшее, значение "морская болезнь". Но оно вряд ли могло стать основой для эвфемизма.

Comment: Нормативной формы единственного числа нет, но почему не может быть- не понимаю. Объект очень даже есть, например, про домашние детские качели, которые в детстве в дверном проходе висели, у нас всегда говорили в единственном числе. Обязательное множественное для меня в свое время стало открытием. Почему множественное, если вот она, передо мной, одна качеля.

Comment: Ларf, так этот "объект" и есть **качели**. Почему о нем надо говорить в единственном?
Вы маленькие ворота назовете "воротом"? 
Пожалуй у всех объектов pluralia tantum только очки могут претендовать на наличие такого одиночного объекта в виде монокля. Хотя и он "очком" не называется.

Comment: Да я не спорю. Просто у нас все говорили в единственном. Дома:"Повесь Леночке качелю", а в парке: "Пойдем кататься на качелях". Но в парке их много. Так и сложился образ единственного-множестенного. Во время учебы в университете пришлось переучиваться. Кстати, ворота в разные стороны раскрываются, у них две створки,  у очков тоже явно две половинки одинаковых. А маленькие домашние детские качели - у них нет ни парности,  ни множественности.

Comment: Интересное, кстати, наблюдение насчет парности. Но ведь есть макароны, шахматы, часы... В вики есть некоторая систематика таких слов и примеры разных типов. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralia_tantum

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке есть существительные, которые имеют форму только множественного числа.

Они могут обозначать:

1) Парные и составные предметы: плоскогубцы, пассатижи, щипцы, бутсы, ножницы, весы, вилы, качели, салазки, счеты, кусачки, носилки, ворота, перила, очки, ножницы, джинсы, брюки, штаны...

2) Игры, действия, процессы: переговоры, выборы, хлопоты, побои, проводы, заморозки, жмурки, горелки...

3) Масса, вещество: деньги, дрожжи, духи, чернила, макароны, сливки, консервы...

4) Отрезки времени: сумерки, будни, сутки, каникулы...

Comment: в качелях всегда есть парная конструкция, удерживающая сидение))

Answer (score 1):

Это учебник В. П. Канакиной и В. Г. Горецкого, 1 часть, с. 134.

В упражнении № 256 приведено стихотворение Т. Андреевой:

```
Улыбнулось солнышко,
Спать ушли метели.
Маленький воробушек
Поднялся с постел...
Сел на ветку тонкую
И под звон капел...
Распевает песенки
На своей качел...
```

Нужно вставить пропущенные окончания и объяснить их правописание.

Если Т. Андреева авторски использует слово "качели" в единственном числе в виде существительного 3 склонения (качель), то окончание будет -и.

Если же это существительное 1 склонения (качеля), то окончание будет -е.

Насколько я поняла, ни то, ни другое правильным не является, **слово "качели" должно употребляться только в форме множественного числа**.

Comment: Аэр! Тут всё по делу! Ща чуток подредактируем! )))

Comment: Кстати о птицах. Мандельштам, 1908: *Я качался в далеком саду
На простой деревянной качели,
И высокие темные ели
Вспоминаю в туманном бреду.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Галина, пользуясь случаем, приглашаю вас заглянуть на Мету, там есть важное сообщение

Comment: Мету нашла, а дальше мне не сориентироваться... 8-(

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/q/135/178412 в самом верху

Comment: Я там запятушку нарисовала вместо тире, и что такое "начиная иллокутивной силой" (интересует не термин)? Почему не "начиная с" (чего-либо)?