# Грамматическая ошибка в предложении!

Tags: грамматика

В чем здесь грамматическая ошибка? Как по мне, предложение корректно:

> "На совещании муниципалитета было решено до конца года установить на
> детских площадках двадцать две качели".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите так:

*На совещании муниципалитета было решено до конца года установить на детских площадках  **качели в количестве 22 штук**.* Рluralia tantum («плюралиа тантум»)!

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480128/Грамматические-правила-русского-языка-для-сущ-очки-ножницы-брюки-и-др/480132](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480128/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80/480132)

Устарело слово...  Но некоторые пользователи не согласны
https://dzen.ru/a/YvFfEgYFezyr9ipX

Осип Мандельштам.
Только детские книги читать…

```
Я качался в далеком саду
На простой деревянной качели,
И высокие темные ели
Вспоминаю в туманном бреду.
1908 г.
```

Comment: Но ведь слово "качель" никуда не исчезло из языка.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24585/Единственное-число-от-слова-качели    https://gramota.ru/meta/kacheli